# push in / snap in panel spring clip edge fastener? help finding product or name

Tags: lock, metal, fastener

I've seen them many times before but can't seem to find the an image, name or product.

You know the clip on your houses circuit breaker panel door that keeps the door closed.  It's a little metal clip M shaped clip that snaps into a metal edge or pin.  Well,  I've seen them on flat panels to secure them over openings in thin sheet metal walls. I have a 6 inch round opening in sheet metal I want to cover with a 7 inch 1/4 plywood and want it to snap in. To open it I would have to apply pressure out to compress the clips.

What is the name of those clips and where can I find them?

They look something like this..but orientation is wrong and seem too thick. the idea is that the clip is attached to the panel and just needs to snap into the substrate.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wood door to cover a metal hole. You could attach some of this **[Super Strong Magnetic Backing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073519752)** to the wood with some epoxy or small pan head screws. This stuff holds 1 pound per an inch of length.
[image]

Comment: thought about it. and I have quart shaped magnets I can hot glue gun in.

Answer (score 0):

Almost any service panel found in a US home will be made by a reputable manufacturer who is still in business and still selling panels of that family.  They will have authorized dealers all over the place, and that will typically be an **electrical supply house**.  Those people will know how to support that panel...  and can sell you either the latch part, door, or cover.

I realize you were just doing it to give a conceptual idea of what the part is, but I must give an obligatory caution against buying any electrical part from Alibaba, Ali Express, eBay or Amazon Marketplace.  Quality matters in these things, and those items don't even try to be safety tested, they just shellack on the "CE" logo which means the manufacturer *promised* to test.

Comment: In this case, I think OP is looking for a product to use on **something other than a circuit breaker panel** but is using that description as a way to find the right item.